# Grafana Loki LogQL: How to parse log lines with different log formats?

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

We have different type of logs for one and the same application. Some are coming from our application which logs in a JSON format and others are different types of log messages.

For example these 3 log lines:

```
"{\"written_at\": \"2022-03-30T07:51:04.934Z\", \"written_ts\": 1648626664934052000, \"msg\": \"Step 'X' started at 2022-03-30 07:51:04\", \"type\": \"log\", \"logger\": \"my-logger\", \"thread\": \"MainThread\", \"level\": \"DEBUG\", \"module\": \"my.module\", \"line_no\": 48}\n"
"                    ERROR    Data processing error: Did not work       \n"
"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/local.json'\n"
```

To parse our application JSON logs we perform the following LogQL query:

```
| json log="log" 
| line_format "{{.log}}"
| json | line_format "{{.msg}}"
| __error__ != "JSONParserErr"
```

As our query already states, we can not parse the other line logs since they are not in JSON format.

**Can we define different parsing and formatting depending on conditions?
Or as fallback when the JSONParserErr happens?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you managed to get an answer to this, as I'm looking to see if this is possible in a single query, however you can do this with multiple queries…

For the JSON rows

```
| json log="log" 
| line_format "{{.log}}"
| json
| line_format "{{.msg}}"
| __error__ != "JSONParserErr"
# … more processing
```

For the non-JSON rows…

```
{swarm_stack="apiv2-acme", swarm_service="apiv2-acme_tenant-import"}
| json
| __error__ = "JSONParserErr"
| drop __error__
# … more processing
```

Comment: That is a bit hacky but I see how one can come up with such "it's not that and therefor will fail here" guard conditions. I think one can make this work for most cases.